# Шаблон для регулярного выражения удалить все символы кроме цифр и запятых

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет подскажите пожалуйста, шаблон для регулярного выражения чтобы удалялись все символы кроме цифр и запятых **(для разделения цифр запятыми)** **количество цифр заранее не известно** запятые, которые между цифрами должны остаться я решаю данную задачу через два шаблона…. Заранее **извиняюсь** если такой вопрос уже был задан Т_Т

---

пример строки : 'str,1,2@,3str,STR,s,4tr,

1. [^\d,]+
2. (?:^,+|,+(?!\d+))

1,2,3,4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно еще так сделать:

```
$str = "'str,1,25@,3str,STR,s,4tr,";
var_dump(join(',',preg_split('/[^\d]+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)));
```

Или одной регуляркой:

```
$str = "'str,1,25@,3str,STR,s,4tr,";
echo preg_replace('/^(?:\D+)|[^\d,]+|,(?!\d)/','',$str);
```

Вывод (одинаковый):

> 1,25,3,4

Answer (score 0):

Сделал конечно как то не эстетично). Но что сразу пришло в голову.
Вот

```
$r = "'str,1,2@,3str,STR,s,4tr,";
$preg = implode(',',array_diff(explode(',',preg_replace('/[^0-9,]/', '', $r)),['']));
```

Если не нашел других решений.